# Google Data Flow Compared to Ms SSIS ETL Tool

Tags: bigdata, google-cloud-dataflow

Hi All GCP Developers,

I am Newbie to GCP Data Engineering Products, With an Experience in Microsoft SSIS ETL Tool, I would like to Know what are the  Various Transformations And Functionalities are available in Google Data Flow. MS SSIS Tool Provide Easy Interface (Drag and Drop ) and SQL Usage to Perform  ETL.

Data flow is mostly written in Python but how do you change or load only certain rows in a CSV/Text File when the particular field value is less than required amount ( Filtering of rows based on one field ) ?

Data flow Name is everywhere(Online)  but why No Documentation of  Data Processing Examples is Available?

If you Know any online course (other than coursera ) or Book with Practical and Hands-on please share it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow is a managed Apache Beam service, so [general Beam quickstarts](https://beam.apache.org/) apply, just set the runner to [DataflowRunner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/).

[Here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/package-summary.html) you can find a summary of available transforms (including the Filter you’d use for the example of filtering rows you mentioned) for the Java SDK. Beam is also available for Python and for Golang, but the Java API is the most mature of the three.

Also, if you want a graphical interface more similar to Microsoft SSIS, you may want to look into [Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/), which is built on top of Dataflow and does provide some more interactive features.